# Timeout in multipart download

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm working on a C# winform application that is downloading by multypart asynchronously.
But, some of part catch request time out error. i try to start fiddler application while my application working. My application work properly and complating download operation for all part.
What effect does Fiddler have on the program's proper functioning?
Is there something I missed from the code I wrote?

```
namespace Vektorel.DownloadManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            nmPartCount.Value = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }

        void AddControl(FlowLayoutPanel panel, ucDownloadStatus download)
        {
            if (panel.InvokeRequired)
            {
                panel.Invoke(new Action<FlowLayoutPanel, ucDownloadStatus>(AddControl), panel, download);
            }
            else
            {
                panel.Controls.Add(download);
            }
        }

        void JoinParts()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath);
            //exenin çalıştığı yerdeki part dosyalarının listesini alalım.
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles().Where(f=>f.Name.Contains(".part")).ToArray();
            //partları birleştirmek için gereken stream
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.GetFileName(txtUrl.Text), FileMode.Create);


            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                //ilgili part'a ait stream.
                FileStream partStream = new FileStream(file.Name, FileMode.Open);
                partStream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        }



        private void btnStartDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebRequest requestForFileSize = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(txtUrl.Text);
            requestForFileSize.Method = "HEAD";
            long totalBytes = Convert.ToInt64(requestForFileSize.GetResponse().Headers["Content-Length"]);
            long partCount = Convert.ToInt64(nmPartCount.Value);
            long partSize = totalBytes / partCount;
            long startIndex = 0;
            Thread[] downloadThreads = new Thread[partCount];
            for (int i = 1; i <= partCount; i++)
            {

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(txtUrl.Text);
                request.Method = "GET";

                string partName = string.Format("part-{0}.part", i);

                if (i == partCount)
                {
                    partSize = totalBytes - startIndex;
                    request.AddRange(startIndex);                    
                }
                else
                {
                    request.AddRange(startIndex, startIndex + partSize);
                }

                startIndex = startIndex + partSize ;

                listBox1.Items.Add(totalBytes);
                listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", partName, partSize));

                downloadThreads[i - 1] = new Thread(() =>
                  {
                      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                      FileStream fs = new FileStream(partName, FileMode.Create);

                      ucDownloadStatus downloadStatus = new ucDownloadStatus();
                      downloadStatus.PartName = partName;

                      AddControl(flowDownloadProgress, downloadStatus);

                      using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                      {
                          using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                          {
                              int openedBytesLength = 0;
                              long totalBytesReceived = 0;
                              while ((openedBytesLength = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                              {
                                  fs.Write(buffer, 0, openedBytesLength);
                                  totalBytesReceived += openedBytesLength;
                                  int progressValue = (int)(totalBytesReceived * 100 / partSize);
                                  downloadStatus.Progress = progressValue;
                                  fs.Flush();
                              }
                          }
                      }
                      fs.Close();
                  });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < downloadThreads.Length; i++)
            {
                downloadThreads[i].Start();
            }

            var complatedThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < downloadThreads.Length; i++)
                {
                    downloadThreads[i].Join();
                }
                JoinParts();
            });
            complatedThread.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be using http 1.1 where the data comes in chunks and you have to request next chunk.  You will get a timeout if you do not send the next chunk message.  Http doesn't work with Net library so you may have to force to use http 1.0.  Check fiddler and see if you are using 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: i tried to adding this line request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; but it isnt working.

Comment: i share screen image https://ibb.co/gKxYUR

Comment: The Url is wrong.  Try : "http://download.winzip.com/gl/nkln/winzip22_downwz.exe"

Comment: My Url is working. This is my url : http://download.winzip.com/winzip220-32.msi

Comment: Are you sure?  I'm getting error not found.  If you click on the link I posted you will get a download.  With yours you do not.

Comment: your url belongs online installer 745 KB. mine is offline installer about 44 MB.

Comment: i share my source code. https://files.fm/u/5htdcbee

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase you wait time by setting timeout value.

request.Timeout=100;

where 100 is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems while download a zip file, try this:

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{


    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {

        (request as HttpWebRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        (request as HttpWebRequest).MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 100;
        (request as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = @"Mozilla / 5.0(Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en - US; rv: 1.8.0.4) Gecko / 20060508 Firefox / 1.5.0.4";

        //CookieContainer make it work
        (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        return response;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
    {

        (request as HttpWebRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        (request as HttpWebRequest).MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 100;
        (request as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = @"Mozilla / 5.0(Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en - US; rv: 1.8.0.4) Gecko / 20060508 Firefox / 1.5.0.4";

        //CookieContainer make it work
        (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result);

        return response;

    }
}
```

To use:

```
client = new MyWebClient();


        //client.DownloadFile("http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_mgsasc.zip", p1);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted1;    

        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/file.zip"), path_name_to_save);

private static void Client_DownloadFileCompleted1(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("download finished");
    }
```

Comment: i tried to applying your solution. But still doesnt work. i share screen image https://ibb.co/gKxYUR

Comment: you can specify a time out for the request:(request as HttpWebRequest).Timeout= 30000;

Comment: i'm trying to set timeout. but not working. i get timeout exception .

Comment: maybe the source of the file not support the number of connections you are trying. This happen with less connections?

Comment: i check download using with 2 part. it's worked. for more than 2 connection (part) i ve the same problem. so you may be right. but i couldnt understand why it is working for more than 2 connection while fiddler (from telerik) program was working.

Comment: the winzip msi of your image accept 3 connections, if you make async and capture the response to check for erros and try again after others parts are sucess downloaded.

Comment: How about fiddler's effect?